# ¿Que debo usar en lugar de componentWillMount() para traer datos de servidor?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, component

recien estoy empezando a aprender ReactJS y estoy mirando los distintos metodos que tiene la subclase Component, estoy mirando que el metodo `componentWillMount()` esta deprecado, y era antes utilizado para realizar la consultas y mostrar los datos luego en el metodo `render()`.

Pero ahora no se donde debo realizar esa consulta, ya que el metodo `constructor()` es el unico que se ejecuta antes de que el componente se "monte", y pienso que dejar todo el codigo amontonado en el contructor puede quedar un poco mal (Es una consulta con fetch). Ademas que el otro metodo es `componentDidMount()` pero se ejecuta una vez esta montado el componente.

Agradezco las aclaraciones que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como la [documentación](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidmount) de [react](/questions/tagged/react) dice:

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

***Traducción***

> `componentDidMount()` is invocado inmediatamente después que un componente es montado (insertado en el árbol). La inicialización que requiere nodos del DOM debería ir aquí. Si necesitas cargar datos desde un punto remoto, este es un buen lugar para instanciar la petición.

Como ya te está en la documentación, la misma gente de Facebook te recomienda hacerlo desde este punto, por algo muy importante, en este punto del ciclo de vida del componente ya tienes disponible el método `setState` por lo que podrás hacer uso del estado del componente como tal, mientras que en el `constructor` solo puedes definir un estado inicial.

***¿Qué quiere decir esto?***

Pues piensa en lo siguiente, el método `constructor` corre de manera sincrónica, es decir, lo ideal es que cualquier código que corras dentro sea sincrónico y no asíncrono (cualidad de las peticiones a servidores, son promesas, código que se ejecuta de manera asíncrona), de tal modo que una vez tu promesa sea resuelta, no tendrías qué hacer ni donde asignar los datos, te pondré un ejemplo:

```
class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    fetch('some-url', {}).then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => {
        // en este punto, no puedes asignar directamente a `setState`
        // porque no sabes si el componente ya tiene acceso a ese método
        // tampoco puedes asignarlo a `this.state` directamente como `initialState`
        // porque como corre de forma sincrónica estarías dañando el curso normal del componente
      });
  }

  render() { return null; }
}
```

Entonces la pregunta es *¿Qué hago con mis datos del servidor?* La respuesta es: A menos que los guardes en un estado global (redux o algún parecido, incluso context) no creo que tengan mucho uso, o dependiendo del tipo de tarea que quieras ejecutar.

Como en el `componentDidMount` ya tienes acceso al método `setState` entonces puedes asignar los datos en tu state sin muchas complicaciones ni verificaciones de si el componente ya está montado o no.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Te explico (en base al comentario), cuando React ejecuta el método `componentDidMount` ya tiene un estado definido a partir del `initialState` (en el ejemplo equivale a cuando defino el `state` como propiedad de la clase) e hizo su primer render, por lo que si tienes contenido en tu método `render` lo más probable es que haga el render antes de llamar el `componentDidMount`. Entonces lo que normalmente se hace es poner un loader o un estado de carga hasta que tu respuesta llegue (esto es algo que harías con cualquier tecnología no solo React)

```
class extends React.Component {
  state = { data: {}, loading: true }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // cuando entre aquí ya hizo el primer render, este estará con el
    // estado `loading` con valor en true
    const response = await fetch('algun-lugar', {});
    // cuando se ejecute la promesa, hará el cambio de estado y mostrará tu
    // contenido de parte del servidor de acuerdo a lo qué hayas definido
    this.setState({ data: await response.json(), loading: false});
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? <div>Cargando...</div> : this.unMetodoQueTrateDataParaRender()
  }
}
```

Cualquier duda que tengas, no dudes en preguntarme y comentar.

Comment: Me quedó mas claro todo, pero y que pasa si lo que debe mostrar ese componente es la respuesta del servidor. ¿Hay un momento donde queda en blanco hasta que carga los datos? o simplemente esto no ocurre

Comment: @Loperso Actualicé la respuesta, puedes echarle un vistazo